# Getting error in console when checking the record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

**Salammobile::Sms.last**

Salammobile::Sms Load (106.1ms)  SELECT `sms`.* FROM `sms` ORDER BY `sms`.`oppid` DESC LIMIT 1
ActiveRecord::SubclassNotFound: The single-table inheritance mechanism failed to locate the subclass: 'international'. This error is raised because the column 'type' is reserved for storing the class in case of inheritance. Please rename this column if you didn't intend it to be used for storing the inheritance class or overwrite Salammobile::Sms.inheritance_column to use another column for that information.
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@salamPlanet/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:153:in `rescue in find_sti_class'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@salamPlanet/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:147:in`find_sti_class'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@salamPlanet/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:136:in `discriminate_class_for_record'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@salamPlanet/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:53:in`instantiate'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@salamPlanet/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/querying.rb:45:in `block in find_by_sql'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@salamPlanet/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/result.rb:21:in`block in each'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@salamPlanet/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/result.rb:21:in `each'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@salamPlanet/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/result.rb:21:in`each'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@salamPlanet/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/querying.rb:45:in `map'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@salamPlanet/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/querying.rb:45:in`find_by_sql'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@salamPlanet/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/relation.rb:585:in `exec_queries'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@salamPlanet/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/relation.rb:471:in`load'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@salamPlanet/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/relation.rb:220:in `to_a'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@salamPlanet/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:340:in`find_last'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@salamPlanet/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:123:in `last'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@salamPlanet/gems/activerecord-deprecated_finders-1.0.3/lib/active_record/deprecated_finders/relation.rb:146:in`last'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@salamPlanet/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/querying.rb:3:in `last'
    from (irb):12
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@salamPlanet/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:90:in`start'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@salamPlanet/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@salamPlanet/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:64:in`'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'

Answer (score 3):

You can't have a database column called `type` in Rails unless it's being used for `ActiveRecord` inheritance mechanism. Rename the column to something else.

Try including this at your class definition:

```
inheritance_column = "class_type"
```

This should make it ignore the `type` column.

Comment: i have not access to change database column how can i get record from this table

Comment: class Salammobile::CountryRate < ActiveRecord::Base
  establish_connection("salammobile")
 

  self.table_name = 'smusers'
  inheritance_column = :_type_disabled
 
endthat is not working basically i am using external database that exist on other server and application is working with different server i put this code now its working  class Salammobile::CountryRate < ActiveRecord::Base
  establish_connection("salammobile")
 

  self.table_name = 'smusers'
 
  self.inheritance_column = nil
end

Answer (score 0):

```
class Salammobile::CountryRate < ActiveRecord::Base
  establish_connection("salammobile")


  self.table_name = 'smusers'
  inheritance_column = :_type_disabled

end
```

that is not working basically i am using external database that exist on other server and application is working with different server i put this code now its working

```
class   Salammobile::CountryRate < ActiveRecord::Base
      establish_connection("salammobile")

      self.table_name = 'smusers'

      self.inheritance_column = nil
    end
```